# Firebase REST API INVALID_ARGUMENT on refresh-token

Tags: php, rest, firebase, firebase-authentication

Yesterday we started to have problems with the REST API in particular with the refresh token method: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-refresh-token

```
curl 'https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=[REFRESH_TOKEN]'
```

We tried this call using the curl example on the documentation and with our own development (with PHP and Guzzle) and we always get this error:

```
"error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this happens when you make that call from inside Google's datacentres, it works fine for us locally. It started happening to us too on the 14th. I've raised a bug with the firebase team.

Comment: Any news from the Firebase team since you raised the bug ? We've been having the same issue as well.

It seems the API has changed without notice and we are unable to make it work.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Just a heads-up: we're having the same issue, don't have a workaround yet.

Comment: Just got a response from the Firebase team : "I've raised the issue you're having to our engineers, and I'll let you know as soon as I get an update." Let's hope this gets fixed quickly !

Comment: Hi All, i just reproduced and have no problems, do you still experience problems?

Comment: Hi @Thomas: Thanks for the infor, but unfortunately, I'm still having the issue yes... Maybe they are deploying as we speak. I'll let you know shortly if thats the case.

Comment: @blackjak231 it seems to be weirder, it works locally but not from within google's infrastructure.

Comment: In our case, we did not need the refresh token nor the id token so we ended up regenerating the custom token entirely and we stopped having issues since then. Hope this can help some people if for you too the refresh and id tokens are not used on server side.

Answer (score 0):

The firebase team got back to me. It seems the issue has been fixed on our side. Can you check it on your side ?

```
Thanks for patiently waiting, and apologies for the inconvenience this might have caused you.

Our engineers have made some changes on our end. Could you please retry and see if the issue persists? 

If yes, please let me know and provide the necessary information that could help us investigate more on the issue.
```

Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem using Python (which uses the same API as was used in the question). I've raised it with Firebase support, and they messaged me today that it was fixed. I've tested it and it works again fine for me, both locally (where it wasn't broken) and from within Google App Engine.

So, it seems the problem was transitory and you should simply try again now.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` into `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`. Then the API will run successfully.

And remember Request body (payload) as below (JSON):

```
{
    "grant_type": "refresh_token",
    "refresh_token": "...current refresh token..."
}
```